# Maven compile error Integer compare

Tags: maven, compiler-errors

```
    cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] symbol  : method compare(java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer)
    [ERROR] location: class java.lang.Integer
```

Getting a strange compile error after trying to run maven on linux for the first time.
Compiles fine on my windows machine. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

This was because maven was using 1.6 compiler of linux and 1.7 on windows. The static compare(Integer,Integer) was added in Java 7.